# regex phrase, positive or negative number/decimal with units

Tags: regex

I am trying to obtain a number in a string. However, the number must follow a very specific pattern in the sentence. We can pretend that I am trying to find the maximum weight for a parcel in a string. For example `The 3rd box marked 4 cannot exceed 7.34kg but if its exact 8.42kg its okay too`. In this case, I want to match the number `7.34`. My pattern in english is:

`<Starts with phrase which is in ('must not exceed', 'cannot exceed', 'limited by')><Can be any characters of any length (0 length to infinite) as long as its not any alphabet characters><a positive or negative int or decimal which may or may not be comma separated (ie. 1,032.43kg)><Can be any characters of any length (0 length to infinite) as long as its not any alphabet characters><ends with the characters which are in ('kg', 'k.g', 'k/g')`

What I have is:

```
(must not exceed|cannot exceed|limited by).*?[0-9]+ ?(kg|k\.g|k\/g)
```

However, the main things I cannot do is be able to match `<Can be any characters of any length (0 length to infinite) as long as its not any alphabet characters>` and `<a positive or negative int or decimal which may or may not be comma separated (ie. 1,032.43kg)>

Some Examples

```
The 3 boxes with red on them must not exceed -23.4435kg and don't pick them up.
Parcels that can be sent are limited by 1,402kg and its okay to send
The 2 boxes on the shelf must not exceed: 
102 kg
Do not pick up 18 boxes at a time and make sure they cannot exceed,: 92302 k.g
Do not pick up boxes that weight 56.23 kg
Boxes cannot exceed -23 k/g
```

I understand that I may need to double regex match. So I regex match the sentence first (ie `must not exceed -23.4435kg` then regex match the number, which is what I am doing in my code at the moment. My question is essentially how do I regex match the correct part of the strings.

Comment: What is the rule for `Do not pick up boxes that weight 56.23 kg`?

Comment: I also think `<Can be any characters of any length (0 length to infinite) as long as its not any alphabet characters>` actually  means "any non-digit (or non-word) chars". You seem to have just some punctuation and space between the word and the numbers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't pick it up since its not part of the rules.

Comment: Ok, so it is not to be matched, I will remove it from my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, it does mean any non-digit (or non-word) chars but can also be nothing. So this part can be 0 characters in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
\b((?:must\s+|can)not\s+exceed|limited\s+by)\W*?(-?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(kg|k\.g|k/g)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/URb3yh/3). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `((?:must\s+|can)not\s+exceed|limited\s+by)` - Group 1: `must not exceed`, `cannot exceed` or `limited by` with any whitespaces in between words
- `\W*?` - any zero or more, but as few as possible, non-word chars
- `(-?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: number pattern, an optional `-`, then one or more digits, then zero or more sequences of `,` and one or more digits, then an optional occurrence of `.` and one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(kg|k\.g|k/g)` - Group 3: `kg`, `k.g` or `k/g`
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5aKKk7):

```py
import re
texts = ['The 3rd box marked 4 cannot exceed 7.34kg but if its exact 8.42kg its okay too',
    'The 3 boxes with red on them must not exceed -23.4435kg and don\'t pick them up.',
    'Parcels that can be sent are limited by 1,402kg and its okay to send',
    'The 2 boxes on the shelf must not exceed: \n102 kg',
    'Do not pick up 18 boxes at a time and make sure they cannot exceed,: 92302 k.g',
    'Do not pick up boxes that weight 56.23 kg',
    'Boxes cannot exceed -23 k/g',
    'must not exceed -23.4435kg']

rx = re.compile(r'\b((?:must\s+|can)not\s+exceed|limited\s+by)\W*?(-?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(kg|k\.g|k/g)\b')
for text in texts:
    print("----", text,"----")
    m = rx.search(text)
    if m:
        print(f"Phrase: {m.group(1)}")
        print(f"Number: {m.group(2)}")
        print(f"UOM: {m.group(3)}")
    else:
        print("Not matched!")
```

Output:

```
---- The 3rd box marked 4 cannot exceed 7.34kg but if its exact 8.42kg its okay too ----
Phrase: cannot exceed
Number: 7.34
UOM: kg
---- The 3 boxes with red on them must not exceed -23.4435kg and don't pick them up. ----
Phrase: must not exceed
Number: -23.4435
UOM: kg
---- Parcels that can be sent are limited by 1,402kg and its okay to send ----
Phrase: limited by
Number: 1,402
UOM: kg
---- The 2 boxes on the shelf must not exceed: 
102 kg ----
Phrase: must not exceed
Number: 102
UOM: kg
---- Do not pick up 18 boxes at a time and make sure they cannot exceed,: 92302 k.g ----
Phrase: cannot exceed
Number: 92302
UOM: k.g
---- Do not pick up boxes that weight 56.23 kg ----
Not matched!
---- Boxes cannot exceed -23 k/g ----
Phrase: cannot exceed
Number: -23
UOM: k/g
---- must not exceed -23.4435kg ----
Phrase: must not exceed
Number: -23.4435
UOM: kg
```

P.S. In Oracle, you will need to throw away word boundaries and replace all non-capturing groups with capturing ones:

```sql
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(
   col,
   '((must\s+|can)not\s+exceed|limited\s+by)\W*?(-?\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?)\s*(kg|k\.g|k/g)',
   1,1, NULL, 3)
```

Comment: Can I ask also, how you are watching the number only. Since I match the full phrase I need. Then I match again just the number. So can I do a second regex that is `(-?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)`

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Just a sec, I will add the Python demo. It is captured into Group 2.

Comment: At the end of the day, I really only want the number. I am currently using oracle sql, so python may be a little too advanced

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov But in Oracle, you will need to only use capturing groups. Its regex engine does not support non-capturing groups and word boundaries.

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov I added the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` code at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. One last question, what does `\s+` mean in `(must\s+` part

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov One or more whitespaces. In Python `re`, it matches any one or more Unicode whitespaces, and is very handy in case your text can contain hard spaces, like `\XA0`.

Comment: I am trying to edit your initial phrase but I am getting errors. Essentially I wanted to add on more beginning phrases like 'shall not pass` and `may not go over`. However, when I do, I am getting errors. the `(must\s+|can)not\s+exceed` is what is really confusing me. when I edit it. Because I know to add more phrases, I separate it with `|` and the the phrase`

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Add it to `(must\s+|can|shall\s+)`. Or just expand it as `(may\s+not\s+go\s+over|shall\s+not\s+pass|must\s+not\s+exceed|cannot\s+exceed|limited\s+by)` if you have trouble understanding how to factor in similar phrases as alternatives.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it with full exact phrases like `(must not exceed|cannot exceed|limited by|shall not pass|may not go over)` Just because they need to be in that exact wording and is easier to add more phrases too. Edit: never mind, i just understood it using the regex demo site